# How to make void (**)() from void()?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-esp32, platformio

Have function:

```cpp
void btCallback(esp_spp_cb_event_t event, esp_spp_cb_param_t *param) { 
    // ...
}
```

Need to use in:

```cpp
BT.register_callback(btCallback);
```

Compiler error:

`no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void(esp_spp_cb_event_t, esp_spp_cb_param_t*)' to 'void (**)(esp_spp_cb_event_t, esp_spp_cb_param_t*)'`

As I understand it, he needs a pointer to function pointer. I don't know how to create it. I tried a function pointer (through &), does not fit.

Reproduction (PlatformIO / platform: espressif32, board: esp-wrover-kit, framework: arduino):

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <BluetoothSerial.h>

BluetoothSerial BT;

void btCallback(esp_spp_cb_event_t event, esp_spp_cb_param_t *param) {
    Serial.println("TEST");
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    BT.begin("", true);
    BT.register_callback(btCallback);
    BT.connect("TEST");
}

void loop() { }
```

P.S. Is arduino-esp32 [BluetoothSerial::register_callback](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/BluetoothSerial/src/BluetoothSerial.cpp#L889) function.

Comment: `esp_spp_cb_t` is `void (*)(esp_spp_cb_event_t event, esp_spp_cb_param_t *param)` The shown error is impossible. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The only way I can see this happening is if someone has been messing with the library headers.

Comment: Added reproduction code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a pointer variable, and then take a pointer from it using the `&` operator.

```cpp
void f()
{
    // ...
}

void g(void (**p)())
{
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    void (*f_ptr)() = f;
    g(&f_ptr);
}
```

Try if [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ThP4ToPWd).

> As I understand it, he needs a pointer to function pointer. I don't
> know how to create it. I tried a function pointer (through &), does
> not fit.

In the previous example, taking `&f` doesn't have any effect. These two lines are equivalent!:

```cpp
void (*f_ptr)() = f;
void (*f_ptr)() = &f;
```

Therefore, if you were doing:

```cpp
g(&f);
```

you are actually passing a simple function pointer, not a pointer to function pointer.